# How to access a class in main.py from another .py file?

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, import

I have class `A` in  `classfile.py` file and I want to access/create an instance of the class where this code is not part of the same `.py` file.

It ends up no instance of class `A` is being created. How can I accomplish that? Is that even possible?

Thanks

#### `classfile.py`:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from createfile import create

    create()
```

#### `createfile.py`:

```
from classfile import A

def create():
    abc = A("hello")
```

Comment: If there is an error message edit the question to show it as properly formatted text.

Comment: The instance of `A` is created, but it's bound to a local variable in the body of `create`, which goes out of scope when `create` returns, leaving the object to be garbage-collected.

Comment: How do you know that no instance is created?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Since I checked it by simply typing "abc" in the shell to see if an instance was created

Comment: @chepner thanks for this hint. I added return to create() and an assign Statement to __main__  `class A(object):


    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from creator import create

    abc = create() `                           `from classfile import A



def create():
    abc = A("hello")

    return abc `

Comment: Don't define things, that you expect to be imported, in your main file. The module will be accessible under two different names: `__main__`, and its module name based off its filename. This can lead to all sorts of weird bugs as the two modules are different objects and so have separate state.